# is there any way to make an image overflow outside a box?

Tags: html, css

I haven't tried yet but here is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Add Your Code Here

Comment: Welcome on SO, you should really try yourself first so we can look at your attempts and give you a more effective help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible approach.

Basically the container of the image is in `absolute` position and its `top/bottom` properties are negative, so it can exceeds the boundaries of the parent section element. The aside text is a flex children, positioned at the `flex-end` and with a `flex-basis` which is `50%` of the parent width.

(A `min-height` is a applied to the section to show the center alignment of the text)

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  border : 1px #ccc solid;
  margin: 60px 10px 120px 10px;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  min-height: 200px;
}

section div {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  align-self: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: .9rem/1.6 system-ui;
}

section p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 25px;
}

section figure {
  position: absolute;
  inset: -50px 50% -50px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

section img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ3pb.jpg" />
  </figure>

  <div>
    <p>
    Cat ipsum dolor sit amet, steal the warm chair right after you get up.
    Bleghbleghvomit my furball really tie the room together damn that dog
    whenever a door is opened, rush in before the human for what a 
    cat-ass-trophy!. Always hungry hide at bottom of staircase to trip human
    stare at the wall, play with food and get confused by dust. My cat stared 
    at me he was sipping his tea, too always hungry. Attack curtains rub face 
    on owner, catto munch salmono but lie on your belly and purr when you are
    asleep poop in litter box, scratch the walls for sweet beast.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>



<section>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ3pb.jpg" />
  </figure>

  <div>
    <p>
    Cat ipsum dolor sit amet, steal the warm chair right after you get up.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```